# AG Grid Not showing icons

Tags: ag-grid, svelte

I am trying to change the default checkbox in AG Grid to custom SVG I have made. The documentation says that AG Grid overrides browser checkboxes to show an icon but that is not the case in my project. I see the default browser provided checkboxes.(Tested in chrome and safari)

I've tried multiple themes too and still no icons.

I am using the AG Grid Svelte wrapper from here:
https://ag-grid-svelte.michael.kim/guide/overview/

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with his for more than 2 hours and finaly I have found that what was removing my ag-grid icons (and some classes) was purgeCSS. It seems that purgeCSS removes some ag-grid CSS as it seems unused for him.
What did the trick was whitelisting the `ag-` classes by using [safelist](https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html).

As my purgeCSS was installed with tailwind and it is loaded in `vite.config.js` , I just changed this:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { purgeCss } from 'vite-plugin-tailwind-purgecss';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        purgeCss()
    ]
});
```

to this:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { purgeCss } from 'vite-plugin-tailwind-purgecss';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        purgeCss({
            safelist: {
                greedy: [/^ag-/],
            },
        })
    ]
});
```